# Is there a way to create an element like <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon> with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, ionicons

I'm using this website https://ionic.io/ionicons to add icons to my buttons and is pretty simple with HTML when declaring a new element (that will encorporate the icon). You just have to declare a button and then put this inside it: `ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon>` .
However I don't know how to create that icon element with javascript because I have to use .createElement at some point in order to make a button appear on the webpage.
Any idea?

I tried the below and it did not work:

```
let dltButton = document.createElement('button');
    dltButton.innerHTML = "<ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon>";
```

is not an official HTML tag, is it? So I assume that is why JS can't create it.

Comment: _"is not an official HTML tag, is it? So I assume that is why JS can't create it."_ - No, the problem is your HTML string literal is not a valid JS string: when you use `"` to delimit a string you cannot then use `"` inside the string (for your HTML attributes), you need to either escape it with a backslash or use single-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```html
<html>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
<body>
  
    <script>
        let dltButton = document.createElement('button');
        dltButton.innerHTML = '<ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon>';
        document.body.appendChild(dltButton);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem might have been that your innerHTMl was double quotes and not single quotes.